# subversion: Is it correct to use svn merge command(with rev B) on already merged code(for rev A)

Tags: svn-merge

I've merged my code with a branch for revision(say X), now there have been commits in the other branch and i want to take those changes in the merged code(which is not committed yet). Now can i run the svn merge command(to say revsion Y) on already modified files.

Assuming in my repo i've src files(say tmp1.c. tm2.c)

code :

```
    $>svn merge rev@branch_out : orig_rev@merge url/to/the/branch/that/is/being/merged/
    U tmp1.c
    A tmp3.c

    $>svn st
    M   tmp1.c
    A + tmp3.c
```

Now the question is can i again do

```
    $>svn merge rev@branch_out : new_rev@merge url/to/the/branch/that/is/being/merged/
```